# Updating SQL SERVER Database from EXCEL

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have an excel sheet with some data:

```
1. Inventory item number 
2. Description
3. Inventory Database ID (PRIMARY KEY)
```

I have about 1000 rows. I want to delete the item numbers in the database that match the item number in my excel list. I can write an application to do that in .NET, but that just seems overly complicated.

Is there an easy way through excel or SQL Server to run a sql statement to delete item numbers in my excel sheet with out the trouble of creating an application?

Comment: do you have access to SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For quick updates. I find this to be the best method.

Add a column to Excel and construct your update statement as a formula, ie:

```
="DELETE Table1 WHERE ItemNumber='"&A1&"' AND InventoryId = "&C1
```

Copy the formula down, and copy/paste the result into an SQL window and run it.

Pro tip, if you have a lot of apostrophes to deal with, it might be worth it to do a global find/replace beforehand. Or you can deal with them from the formula. ie:

```
="DELETE Table1 WHERE ItemNumber='"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'","''")&"' AND InventoryId = "&C1
```

Comment: for the apostrophes, you can do a quick update to your formula `="DELETE Table1 WHERE ItemNumber='"&substitute(A1,"'","")&"' AND InventoryId = "&C1`

Comment: Thanks @nutsch, I updated my answer to be more thorough. Usually a global find/replace is safe as adding the column kind of destroys the file for other purposes anyway.

Comment: I am not sure that is going to work for me. I have about 500 rows to delete. 10-20 rows maybe, any more than that it will be too much work..

Comment: Why is it too much work? The formula @Malk gave can simply be filled down, copied, pasted, and executed. Are there other requirements?

Comment: could i generate a script and run through ssms? like
'code'
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE itemnumber=123
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE itemnumber=124
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE itemnumber=125
'code'
and run each line?

Comment: I got it.. new query file and cut and paste all of them... thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to go through a SQL interface, you can run the attached code from excel, after updating the connection string obviously.

```
Sub ExecuteSQLCommand()
'Execute the SQL string passed through

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, strConn As String, sSQLCommand As String
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command, lLoop As Long, lLastRow As Long

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
                                "Data Source=DCC08SQL;" & _
                                "Initial Catalog=HarvestPress;" & _
                                "Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
                                "Database=HarvestPress;" & _
                                "Trusted_Connection=True;"

conn.Open

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandType = adCmdText

    For lLoop = 1 To lLastRow
        sSQLCommand = "DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE ItemNumber='" & Cells(lLoop, 1) & "' AND InventoryId = " & Cells(lLoop, 1)
        .CommandText = sSQLCommand
        .Execute
    Next lLoop

End With

conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing

End Sub
```